# .NET bug/issue tracking system with Mercurial support

Tags: .net, mercurial, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I'm looking for a opensource bug/issue tracking system with support for Mercurial. It has to run on IIS 6.0, so it would be nice if it was written in .NET.

Do you have any experience with such software, and anything you can recommend?

Edit: Has to run on MSSQL aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) is written in .net and has Mercurial integration, but I don't have any experience with it (yet).

I'm just evaluating myself, and I only read about it, but haven't tried it yet.

*(Unfortunately, most of the more known bug tracking systems are not .net based. A few days ago I tried to install Redmine, but I gave up after [spending some time](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache), having no previous experience with Ruby, Rails, Apache...you get the idea :-/)*

Comment: I see. I have searched the net for hours, not finding anything but BugTracker.NET. Maybe I should give it a go, but it looks horrible. Actually I was looking into Redmine aswell, but what I didn't mention earlier, was that it has to run on MSSQL. Redmine doesn't.

Comment: That's one thing that confused me as well. The first Redmine link that I read was the German wikipedia article (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine), and it says that Redmine DOES run on MSSQL.
When I read the installation instructions on redmine.org, I realized that it does not run on MSSQL.